# What Is The Best HDR Software?

Tags: software-recommendation

How can I go about HDRI software for Ubuntu 12.04 Beta2? Your help would be highly. appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at [Luminance HDR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtpfsgui/).
These [notes](http://wiki.panotools.org/Luminance_HDR) might be useful.
It was called [Qtpfsgui](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/qtpfsgui/) earlier.

And [fotoxx](http://kornelix.squarespace.com/fotoxx/) (from the comments here) is also an Ubuntu package -- Looks promising, I'll try it too.

Comment: It is still called `qtpfsgui` in 12.04 beta2, so search for that in software center or in terminal `sudo apt-get install qtpfsgui`. Another utility is `fotoxx` but I have no  experience using it.

Answer (score 18):

There are some great tools for the Photographer to utilize. I can name more than a dozen but lets focus on the main object. Getting the right look for an HDR photo.

---

You will need [Ufraw](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/) to process RAW photos

You will need [Luminance HDR](http://qtpfsgui.sourceforge.net/) and the [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) plug-in to process HDR images

You will need [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) for the final touches

---

Let me cover 3 things to be able to develop HDR photos

Setup or Pre-process:

Taking the photos is just the beginning to the end. You will need 3 or more photos of the same object, from the same distance with the same focus but with different exposures.

See this Tutorial for [Pre-Process](http://digital-photography-school.com/setting-up-your-digital-camera-for-hdr-shooting) setup and recommendations

---

HDR Development:

This is where the magic starts to happen. Using 3, 5, 7, 9 or more photos you will have a deviation of exposures and will combined them using the software indicated. The Hugin plugin is used for straightening the edges and layering the images on top of each other.

See this Tutorial for [HDR Development](http://www.dr-lex.be/info-stuff/luminancehdr.html) using Luminance

---

Post processing:

I like to use GIMP to manipulate the final image settings. This way the photographer gives the photo its final blessing.

See this Tutorial for [Post Processing](http://www.linuceum.com/videoPage.php?id=14) using GIMP

Comment: I "was" going to add an answer, but your awesome answer here would only cause my self-esteem to go down ^^. How about adding http://enblend.sourceforge.net/ which is the only up to date missing from the list that I know of.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado thanks, and your enblend is not a HDR application, more of a sticher that is able to composite pieces of photos.

Comment: Its still a good reference.

Comment: Note: Luminance HDR is capable of using Hugin to auto-align images so it isn't a _hard_ requirement that they be perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Macrofusion - maybe not best, but worth to try:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/macrofusion/
... and PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~dhor/+archive/myway

Disclaimer: I am the developer/maintainer of Macrofusion.

Comment: After I import some pictures and change some settings and click "Preview" all I see is this: http://i.imgur.com/VaVfPzD.png Is there something I can do about that?

Comment: I guess its a bug, this is what I get in the terminal when I click "preview": http://paste.ubuntu.com/6907173/

Answer (score 0):

For me it depends for what arrangement you need it. For example, for iPhone or for MAC. By the way, for MAC I recommend the next one: https://aurorahdr.com/ You already have a pending invitation to this account which I found very efficient.

Comment: Sorry, this answer doesn't help Ubuntu users.